# QModelIndex becomes invalid when removing rows

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I'm subclassing `QAbstractItemModel` to display items in a `QTreeView`, and within this subclass (`projectModel`), I have a function to delete the currently-selected index in the tree view.  `Component` is the class used to represent all the members of the model:

```
void
projectModel::deleteComponent()
{
    QModelIndex child_index = _treeview->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    Component* child = static_cast<Component*>(child_index.internalPointer());

    Component* parent = child->Parent();
    QModelIndex parent_index = createIndex(parent->row(), 0, parent);

    int row = child->row();

    beginRemoveRows(parent_index, row, row);
    parent->delete_child(child);
    endRemoveRows();
}
```

The parent and child indicies and raw pointers are good just before the call to `beginRemoveRows`; debugger shows that they point to the correct item and its parent.  However, the program crashes after calling `beginRemoveRows`.  Specifically, it crashes in  `projectModel::parent()`:

```
QModelIndex
projectModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{    
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    Component* item = getItem(index);        //Fails to cast index internal pointer to a valid Component*
    Component* parentItem = item->Parent();

    if (parentItem == _rootnode)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}
```

When I break on the crash and examine the debugger output, it shows that the variable `item` in the `parent()` function is garbage.  Somehow it looks like my `QModelIndex` gets corrupted between the call to `deleteComponent` and the call to `parent`.  Is there anything blatantly wrong with what I'm doing, or is the problem perhaps more subtle?

Comment: Side note: A model should never hold any references to the view, since it is perfectly valid to use a model with zero views, as well as with "views" that don't subclass `QAbstractItemView`. The `deleteComponent` method belongs somewhere outside of the model class. Most likely, you should subclass `QTreeView`.

Comment: I'd also `Q_ASSERT(child_index.isValid())`, since it doesn't have to be valid.

Comment: What is the call stack when it crashes? You probably shouldn't be calling `deleteComponent` while any view code you don't have control over is on the call stack.

Comment: Update: upon further inspection, the crash happens somewhere between the call to `beginRemoveRows` and the call to `delete_child`.  There are several calls to `projectModel::parent()` during the remove-rows process, and it is one of these where it finally crashes.  I suspect I have a `QModelIndex` stored somewhere that is becoming invalidated during this process.  Thanks for your help so far, @KubaOber.

Comment: The call stack is useless in this case because the invalid QModelIndex wasn't invoked until long after the model structure changed.  By that time, the offending function had already returned and disappeared from the call stack.  This was an especially difficult bug to fix for that reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fully expected.

Non-persistent indices are valid until you change the structure of the model. A structural change is any change that is signaled *other* than by emitting `dataChanged`.

Structural changes must be considered barriers to index lifetime: you must discard any non-persistent indices held from before a structural change.

Depending on where `deleteComponent` is called, likely what happens is that the caller holds some indices, the `deleteComponent` invalidates them all, and you're in undefined behavior territory from there onwards.

You need to use persistent indices if you want them to stay valid over structural changes, and even then they'll only be valid if the given item still exists. If you're using your own model, you need to explicitly support persistent indices, and the users of your model must use them.

Comment: *"which models support persistent indices"* Actually, all models. If a model fails  to update its persistent indexes it's a bug in the model.

Comment: @peppe Since the documentation doesn't say that they are optional, you'd think they are not. But not all models support them. It's a "bug" in the sense that nobody bothered implementing them. Qt's views don't use them, so it's not a big deal if you limit yourself to those.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with that? Which models "don't support" them?

Comment: @peppe AFAIK, `QStandardItemModel` does, and that's it. SQL models don't, and these are the ones that really could use them - thus you can't re-sort an SQL table model while preserving selections :( Simple models like `QStringListModel` don't either IIRC. Qt's old model-view system needs a serious looking after, but I've been too busy to take any of it up.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that SQL models don't support "layout changed" notifications (such as sorting), instead they just reset themselves because they need to run a different SQL query. But this doesn't mean they don't support persistent indexes -- they do. For instance QSqlTableModel supports row insertion, which means the persistent indexes *do* get updated.

Comment: I think this fixed it.  I had a few objects that were storing `QModelIndex`s as member variables, so possibly they became invalidated when the model structure changed.  I got rid of those member indices and so far I haven't had any crashes.  The problem was intermittent to begin with, so I'm not 100% it's fixed.  Will mark as solved anyway.  Thanks @KubaOber.

Comment: Another update: I consider my problem officially solved now.  There were two main causes: one, I was changing the structure of the model externally, without notifying the model, and second, I was storing QModelIndexes in objects where they outlived the actual indexes that they represented.  On top of that, some of those objects were being leaked (not part of *this* problem, but a problem none the less).  I feel like I should quit my job and go work at McDonalds.

Comment: @Carlton We all have to learn somehow. Good job on nailing down the other problems!