# Delete rows from QTreeView with custom model

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt. I'm trying to create custom model for tree view with support of rows deletion. I've implemented it according to examples http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html. Also, I've made context menu with option to remove row after pressing with right mouse button on the row.

Now, I have hardly reproducible error (there is no exact pattern, but it is easy to obtain). When I start to delete rows from model randomly, sometimes my program crashes, sometimes I receive following messages to output:

```
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 1 , 0 ) in model QAbstractItemModel(0x55555580db10)
```

When program crashes, I almost always in fuction

```
QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
```

which is inherited from

```
QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
```

Stack of function calls shows that this function is called from

```
void QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveRows(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
```

which I call in overrided

```
bool TreeModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
```

When I compared adresses of child.indernalPointer() (where I store pointer to internal tree Nodes, representing my model) with already deleted Nodes, It became clear, that by some reason beginRemoveRows() using already invalid indices.

There is question with very similar error: [QModelIndex becomes invalid when removing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569424/qmodelindex-becomes-invalid-when-removing-rows), howerer I can't understand why and where I use invalid indices.

So, I place the minimal example with this behavior (I've put a lot of effort to minimize it to this size and make the code clear, sorry for it is nevertheless long).

**tree.pro**

```
QT       += core gui widgets
TARGET = tree
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES +=  main.cpp  widget.cpp  treemodel.cpp
HEADERS +=  widget.h  treemodel.h
```

**treemodel.h**

```
#ifndef TREEMODEL_H
#define TREEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractItemModel>

class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
public:
    TreeModel();
    ~TreeModel();

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent) override;

private:
    class Impl;
    Impl* impl = nullptr;
};

#endif // TREEMODEL_H
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void projectTreeMenuRequested(const QPoint& point);
    void eraseItem();
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl* impl;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**treemodel.cpp**

```
#include "treemodel.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

namespace {

struct Node {
    Node(const std::string& name)
        : text(name)
    {
    }
    ~Node() {
    }

    Node& append(const std::string& name) {
        child.emplace_back(name);
        Node& n = child.back();
        n.parent = this;
        return n;
    }
    size_t getChildNum() const {
        return child.size();
    }
    bool hasParent() const {
        return parent != nullptr;
    }
    Node& getParent() {
        assert(hasParent());
        return *parent;
    }
    size_t getIndexInParent() const {
        if (parent) {
            size_t index = 0;
            Childs::iterator it = parent->child.begin();
            while (it != parent->child.end()) {
                if (&*it == this) {
                    return index;
                }
                ++it;
                ++index;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    Node& getChild(size_t i) {
        assert(i < child.size());
        Childs::iterator it = child.begin();
        std::advance(it, i);
        return *it;
    }
    void setText(std::string name) {
        this->text = std::move(name);
    }
    std::string getText() const {
        return text;
    }
    void remove() {
        assert(hasParent());
        Node& p = getParent();
        for (Childs::iterator it = p.child.begin(); it != p.child.end(); ++it) {
            if (&*it == this) {
                p.child.erase(it);
                return;
            }
        }
        assert(0); // Child for remove not found
    }
    bool removeChilds(size_t start, size_t end) {
        if (start < end && end <= child.size()) {
            Childs::iterator it1 = child.begin();
            assert(it1 != child.end());
            std::advance(it1, start);
            assert(it1 != child.end());
            Childs::iterator it2 = it1;
            std::advance(it2, end - start);
            child.erase(it1, it2);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static const int Columns = 1;

private:
    using Childs = std::list<Node>;

    std::string text;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    Childs child;
};

} // namespace

struct TreeModel::Impl {
    Impl()
        : root("Root")
    {
        fill(root);
    }

    void fill(Node& from, std::string str = "", int depth = 0) {
        if (depth == 10) return;
        for (int j = 0; j != 5; ++j) {
            std::string name = str + std::to_string(j);
            fill(from.append(name), name, depth+1);
        }
    }

    Node root;
};

TreeModel::TreeModel()
    : impl(new Impl)
{

}

TreeModel::~TreeModel()
{
    delete impl;
}

QModelIndex
TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent)) {
        return QModelIndex();
    } else {
        Node* node = nullptr;
        if (!parent.isValid()) {
            node = &impl->root;
        } else {
            node = static_cast<Node*>(parent.internalPointer());
        }
        return createIndex(row, column, &node->getChild(row));
    }
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    if (!child.isValid()) {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    Node* node = static_cast<Node*>(child.internalPointer());
    if (!node->hasParent()) {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    return createIndex(node->getIndexInParent(),
                       child.column(),
                       &node->getParent());
}

int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Node* p = nullptr;
    if (parent.isValid()) {
        p = static_cast<Node*>(parent.internalPointer());
    } else {
        p = &impl->root;
    }
    return p->getChildNum();
}

int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return Node::Columns;
}

QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.isValid()) {
        Node* node = static_cast<Node*>(index.internalPointer());
        switch (role) {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        case Qt::EditRole:
            return QString::fromUtf8(node->getText().data(),
                                     node->getText().size());
            break;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role != Qt::EditRole)
        return false;

    Node* node = nullptr;
    if (index.isValid()) {
        node = static_cast<Node*>(index.internalPointer());
    } else {
        node = &impl->root;
    }
    node->setText(value.toString().toStdString());

    emit dataChanged(index, index);

    return true;
}

Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return 0;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable | QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
}

bool TreeModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Node* node = nullptr;
    QModelIndex correctParent;
    if (parent.isValid()) {
        node = static_cast<Node*>(parent.internalPointer());
        correctParent = parent;
    } else {
        node = &impl->root;
        correctParent = QModelIndex();
    }

    beginRemoveRows(correctParent, row, row + count - 1); // [row, row + count - 1]
    bool success = node->removeChilds(row, row + count); // [row, row + count)
    endRemoveRows();

    return success;
}
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QMenu>

#include "treemodel.h"

struct Widget::Impl {
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
    QTreeView* treeView;
    TreeModel* treeModel;
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , impl(new Impl)
{
    impl->layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    impl->treeView = new QTreeView;
    impl->treeModel = new TreeModel;

    impl->layout->addWidget(impl->treeView);
    impl->treeView->setModel(impl->treeModel);
    impl->treeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
    impl->treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(impl->treeView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
            this, SLOT(projectTreeMenuRequested(const QPoint&)));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete impl->treeModel;
    delete impl;
}

void Widget::projectTreeMenuRequested(const QPoint &point)
{
    QPoint globalPos = impl->treeView->mapToGlobal(point);

    QMenu myMenu;
    myMenu.addAction("Erase",  this, SLOT(eraseItem()));

    myMenu.exec(globalPos);
}

void Widget::eraseItem()
{
    for (QModelIndex index : impl->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()) {
        impl->treeModel->removeRow(index.row(), index.parent());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think about two ways to solve the problem. The first is direct approach when somebody point me to the incorrect use of Qt API. The second approach is if somebody write independent implementation of this functionality (tree with infinity nesting and ability to remove) and I will try to figure out what I am doing wrong compared to another implementation.

**EDIT 2**

After thorough analysis of QStandardItemModel I come to conclusion, that it is important to store in **internalPointer** of indices **parent** of actual Node, but in my example I use **internalPointer** to store Node itself. So it seems correct for Qt internal implementation to call parent() on indices of already deleted elements, assuming that the information in **indernalPointer** is not related to element and remains correct. (Please, correct me if I am wrong.)

> Confirmed, that after rewriting implementation to store pointers to parent node in internal nodes, this bug was eliminated. Correction of other bugs is provided in accepted answer.

Comment: According to the debugger the error is given in `++it;` of the `getIndexInParent()` method that is called by `createIndex()`, you have to verify that the next element exists.

Comment: @eyllanesc My debugger shows exactly this behavior, as I noted in question, the method getIndexInParent() called from already deleted Node. (called from TreeModel::parent() as first argument to createIndex()).

Comment: I've fighted with (or better against) the `QAbstractItemModel` quite long. Qt samples didn't help so much due to my data model and lazy filling of nodes (as my data model may have cyclic references which must be resolved upon user request only). After a lot debugging (and a lot of head-ache) it's  stable now (I hope). The last big improvement, I achieved by putting `qDebug()`s into anything which deals with `QModelIndex`. I was shocked how often e.g. `parent()` is called even on nodes which were neither subject of interaction nor modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using for(index: selectedIndexes()) in Widget::eraseItem(), but after removing something, indexes changes, so your index in for becomes invalid. Also, it is a bad practice, to change container while you iterating through it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this mistake. This problem is really present in my code. So the solution might be to copy selected indices to persistent indices and iterate over persistent indices. However this solves only part of problem: deleting multiple elements at once. Actually, the bug described in question still present, it can be reproduced if you try to delete only single elements at once (by deleting **impl->treeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);** from **widget.cpp**).

Comment: Better not to use indexes, but some meta property, like “I’d”, that doesn’t visible, but unique and never changes. You getting selected indexes, than you parse list of id’s and using your remove(list<I’d>) method, remove all you need. Something like this.

Comment: I compiled your code. You have some other problems. Root Node must have invalid index(QModelIndex()). Cause there too much code, i paste it to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/UkL4hFXS

Comment: Can you tell where exactly to look? Now I found only one crucial difference in function parent(): **if (!node->hasParent() || node->parent == &impl->root)**. Do you say that there is general rule, that every invalid index and root index should be specified only by **QModelIndex()**? Or maybe there are some exceptions?

Comment: `Node* node = parent.isValid() ? static_cast<Node*>(parent.internalPointer()) : &impl->root;` in removeRows() and  `if (!node->hasParent() || node->parent == &impl->root) {
        return QModelIndex();
    }` in parent().
Cause Root must be QModelInedx(), internal pointer will return 0x0, so you need to specify pointer to it in removeRows.

Comment: I fixed it according you suggestion, it is of course right, but the main problem still here.

Comment: I don't have any troubles, if i removing 1 row. If you try to remove more then 1, then you need to change your erase method: id's Instead of indexes, and using removeRow, or you can use removeRows if rows to remove are successive.(read 1 answer)

Comment: Now it is much harder to reproduce, but it is still here. I am using your version from pastebin, with depth = 5 and deleted string `impl->treeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);`

Comment: While testing, i found interesting bug, sometimes node's parent in getIndexInParent() have 0xfeefee adress(so it's deleted). I think there can be some problems in your Node relations implementation. Also, Qt have example of TreeModel. [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html)
P.s. sorry, can't help anymore :c

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is not a bug, but details of Qt internal implementation, which I described in Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

In removeChilds() try changing the conditional from end <= child.size() to end < child.size()

Comment: Thank you for answer, but removeChilds expects second argument to be the number of element, next to last element to be deleted. (like n when iterating in for (i = 0; i < n; i++)). If I make this change, I won't be able to delete last element in each subtree.